# Window onmessage/message event does not work in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, events, event-handling

I am trying to get the data from an external window with the help of messageEvent of Java script.

```
function damCallBack() {
  var callBackUrl = 'url to be redirected';
  var myWindow = window.open(callBackUrl, "Select Content", "width=750,height=550");
  // Create IE + others compatible event handler
  var eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
  var eventer = window[eventMethod];
  var messageEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";
  // Listen to message from child window
  eventer(messageEvent, function(e) {
    var dataReceived = JSON.parse(e.data);
    var imageId = dataReceived.data[0].assetid;
    alert(imageId);
    if (dataReceived) {
      myWindow.close();
    } else {
      console.log("Looks we have not received any data. Here was the data " + dataReceived + " ");
    }
  }, false);
}
```

This is working fine in both Chrome and Firefox. But failed to work in IE. Any reason for this not to work on IE?

I have gone through the [message | onmessage in IE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197057(v=vs.85).aspx). But no luck

Comment: which version of IE you are trying? and also is your 'callBackUrl' is from different origin?

Comment: I am using IE11 and my callback url is in other domain

Comment: IE does not support postMessage between cross-domain popup window

Comment: If I do var myWindow = window.open("/", "Select Content", "width=750,height=550");
 myWindow .location.href  = callBackUrl; then it is working on IE 11